# Как переправить данные частями из файла

Tags: c++, mpi

Добрый день!
Пишу программу на C++ при использование интерфейса передачи сообщений (MPI) и столкнулся с одной проблемой.
Необходимо считать данные из текстового файла и передать их другим потокам.
Собственно вся загвоздка именно в том, как реализовать передачу данных из текстового файла частями, чтобы затем потоки которые приняли эти данные, выполняли последующие необходимые операции уже не со всеми данными из файла, а лишь с их частью.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел отличную функцию для такой отправки - MPI_Scatter.
Так что вопрос можно считать закрытым.

Comment: @rfry, так закройте. Под вопосом есть строчка ... "закрыть" ...

Comment: @avp она похоже только у вас есть :)

Comment: Видимо это вопрос к ХэшКоду. 

Почему **автор вопроса** не может (независимо от очков) закрыть **свой** вопрос ?

Сейчас (из Справки по форуму)  закрытие своего вопроса: 250

--

Если автор желает закрыть, то я могу.

Answer (score -1):

Я правильно понял - вопрос в том, как считать файл по кускам??
fread в помощь, если так)

Comment: К сожалению не знаком с MPI. 

Но если речь о потоках, аналогичных posix threads, то либо в каждом потоке надо открывать свой FILE, либо потоки должны синхронизировать свои обращения к файлу и правильно делать fseek() в нем перед чтением. 

Т.к. все они разделяют один и тот же ресурс.

Comment: В MPI параллелизм реализуется через процессы, а не потоки.

Comment: @mikillskegg, Спасибо, буду знать. 

А механизм передачи открытого дескриптора файла (ну, в Linux это можно через sendmsg()) в MPI есть ?

Comment: @avp Нет, процессы могут выполняться на разных машинах, данные обычно читает один процесс и раздаёт их остальным. Но можно в разных процессах читать данные из разных файлов или из одного, используя сетевую файловую систему, смонтированную на всех машинах одинаковым образом.